# Nfc-v can't figure how to retrieve same data as other app

Tags: android, hex, nfc

I write a code that read data from an NFC-v tag. 
With that code i can read binary data from the card.

When i decode this data to Hexa i got the same memory data as an Android app `NXP Taginfo`.

But i want to recover the section under `Application information`

Here is a dump of the hexa that i retreive from their app

```
-- INFO ------------------------------

# IC manufacturer:
EM Microelectronic-Marin SA

# IC type:
EM4x3x

# Application information:
SKIDATA keycard
* Key number: xx-16147133534646198558-x

-- NDEF ------------------------------

# No NFC data set storage:

-- EXTRA ------------------------------

# Memory size:
208 bytes
* 52 blocks, with 4 bytes per block

# IC detailed information:
Supported read commands:
* Single Block Read
* Multiple Block Read
* Get Multiple Block Security Status
* Get System Information
AFI supported
DSFID supported
IC reference value: 0x02
Customer ID: 0x066

-- TECH ------------------------------

# Technologies supported:
ISO/IEC 15693-3 compatible
ISO/IEC 15693-2 compatible

# Android technology information:
Tag description:
* TAG: Tech [android.nfc.tech.NfcV, android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable]
android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable
android.nfc.tech.NfcV
* Maximum transceive length: 253 bytes


# Detailed protocol information:
ID: E0:16:24:66:09:62:61:1E
AFI: 0x00
DSFID: 0x02

# Memory content:
You don't need it for find the number

  x:locked, .:unlocked
```

How can i decode the memory content to retrieve this key number?

Answer, as Yrtiop says you need to read the card ID, here is the correct function to do it :

```
byte[] arrayOfByte = cardNfcTag.getId();
    for (int i1 = -1 + arrayOfByte.length; i1 >= 0; i1--)
    {
      Object[] arrayOfObject = new Object[1];
      arrayOfObject[0] = Integer.valueOf(0xFF & arrayOfByte[i1]);
      localStringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X", arrayOfObject));
    }
    BigInteger localBigInteger = new BigInteger(localStringBuilder.toString(), 16);
return "xx-" + localBigInteger.toString() + "-x";
```

XX are the card type, and the last x is an CRC to validate the key number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i can read on the doc : http://www.emmicroelectronic.com/sites/default/files/public/products/datasheets/em4133_ds.pdf

To get the key number you must read the UID, and there is a mask to apply when you read the bytes, as shown on the point 7.2 of the doc.

Comment: Thx Yrtiop, you're right, the needed info is in the key ID.